# Apache2 Forbidden Access

Tags: apache

I have tried a number of suggestions/answers for similar problems but none have helped!

I am running an Apache2..4.7 on ubuntu 14.4, I've done

```
mkdir /var/www/html/download
cp src /var/www/html/download/file.extn
```

While the request localhost or 127.0.0.1 and surprisingly 127.0.1.1 are returning Ubuntu default page,
http://127.0.0.1/download/file.extn is giving

> Forbidden
>   You don't have permission to access /download/file.extn on this server.
>   Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at 127.0.0.1 Port 80

Error log says:

> (13)Permission denied: [client 127.0.0.1:52345] AH00035: access to /download/apkFile.apk denied (filesystem path '/var/www') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path

apache2.conf has been changed to:

```
Directory
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
Require all granted
Directory

Directory /usr/share
AllowOverride None
Require all granted
Directory

Directory /var/www/
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
Require all granted
Directory

Directory /var/www/html/download
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
Require all granted
Directory
```

Permission to all directories leading to `/var/www/html/download/file.extn` has been chmod to 644.

Comment: directories should be 755, not 644...

Comment: apache/Wiki at https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/13PermissionDenied says files should be 644, does it mean directories should be 755 and files 644?